# Laravel 4.2 throwing MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I have this code which worked in previous versions, now doesn't work anymore. I'm doing simple user authourization like this:

Form:

```
 {{ Form::open(array(
        'url'       => 'login',
        'method'    => 'PUT',
        'class'     => 'pure-form pure-form-stacked'
  )) }}

                    {{ $errors->first('email') }}
                    {{ $errors->first('password') }}

                    {{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), array('placeholder' => 'user')) }}
                    {{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder' => 'password')) }}    

                    {{ Form::submit('Log in', array('class'=>'button-primary')) }}


   {{ Form::close() }}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('login', array('https', function(){
return View::make('back-end/login');
}));

Route::post('login', array('https', function(){
$userdata = array(
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
);

if(Auth::attempt($userdata)){
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
}));


Route::group(['before' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'dashboard'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@getDashboard');
    Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController');
    Route::get('logout', [
           'as'   => 'logout',
           'uses' => 'UserController@getLogout'
        ]); 
});
```

Login page will load, but when i submit form i get in output MethodNotAllowedHttpException.

Comment: change the method from `put` to `post`.

Answer (score 3):

Your login route is a `POST`, but your form is using `PUT`. Switch `'method'    => 'PUT',` to `'method'    => 'POST',` in your `Form::open` call (as you shouldn't be using `PUT` anyways there) and it should work.

Comment: I did that, but then i get "404 Not Found".

Comment: What does `php artisan routes` output?

Comment: That all routes exist, which doesn't make sense, if credentials are wrong it should reload login page instead of throwing not found error.

Comment: Try showing us the output of `php artisan routes` - there may be something subtle there which other eyes might be able to pick up.